# On upload rename the file to input.mp4 not working

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Ok so i'm trying to make it to were the file is uploaded then renamed to input.mp4 so that it over rights the old one. But its not working?

But it still keeps uploading with the original file name.
Or is there a way to just delete the files in the folder uploads after 30 min? Both the uploaded file and output file.

```
<?php
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
    echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
    exit();
}

    $newfilename = $fileName . input.mp4';
    rename($fileName, $newfilename);

if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "uploads/$newfilename")){

  echo "Starting ffmpeg... <br />";
  echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -y -i uploads/".$newfilename." uploads/output.mp3");
  echo "Done. <br /><br />";

echo '<a href="http://test.tw-wcs.com:82/ffmpeg/MP4_To_MP3/uploads/output.mp3" target="_blank">Click Here</a> To open your file in a new tab.';

} else {
    echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you using rename() and move uploaded file? What you are trying to do with rename is to move/rename the file $filename, which doesnt exist. That is just the name of the file, not the name of the file placed on the server. I would remove rename (+ you have an error here: `$newfilename = $fileName . input.mp4';`  should be `$newfilename = $fileName . 'input.mp4';`). And then apply the move_uploaded_file in the way Kevin explained below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'tmp_name'` index is the temporary path where the file is stored. `move_uploaded_file` moves the file from this `$source` path to the `$destination` path and makes this temporary file a permanent one by storing it in a different location. If you don't move this file away from the temporary directory it will be deleted after the script finished executing.

```
$source = $fileTmpLoc;
$destination = YOUR_DIRECTORY . '/' . $fileName . '.input.mp4';
move_uploaded_file($source, $destination);
```

Comment: i meant that it renames the file uploaded from filename.mp4 to input.mp4

Comment: i did it i just did $source = $fileTmpLoc;
$destination = 'uploads/input.mp4';

if(move_uploaded_file($source, $destination)) {